# Count occurrences of a given string in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of strings , I browse it and count number of "x" strings as below but the count doesn't print me the expected value:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<String> strings = table.getValue(); //this gives  ["y","z","d","x","x","d"]

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    if ((strings.get(i) == "x")) {
        count++;
        list.add(count);
    }
}

System.out.println(list);
```

this gives `[]` it should be 2 as I have 2 occurrences of "x"

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` use `equals()`.

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList to count?

Comment: I wonder how much less traffic SO would get if the Java compiler were to warn on `==` comparison of strings...

Comment: ok, I 've changed to equals, the problem now is that print me [1,2] instead of[2] ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There already is an [existing method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) for this:

```
Collections.frequency(collection, object);
```

In your case, use like this (replace all of your posted code with this):

```
System.out.println(java.util.Collections.frequency(table.getValue(), "x"));
```

Comment: ok, thanks! so we can use collections directly as you've mention ?

Comment: @Iola: yes, it's a static method, that's how you use it.

Answer (score 4):

You should compare strings using `equals` instead of `==`. I.e. change

```
if ((list.get(i) == "x"))
                 ^^
```

to

```
if ((list.get(i).equals("x")))
                 ^^^^^^
```

`==` compares references, while `.equals` compares actual content of strings.

---

**Related questions:**

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [Java Compare Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730907/java-compare-strings)
- [Comparing strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700357/comparing-strings-in-java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116595/compare-two-strings-java
- [What's the quickest way to compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805601/whats-the-quickest-way-to-compare-strings-in-java)
- [String Comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java)
- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- [How do I make my string comparison case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220400/compare-two-strings-in-java)
- [comparing strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505981/comparing-strings-in-java)
- [Strings don't seem to be equal in Java on Android, even though they print the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704956/strings-dont-seem-to-be-equal-in-java-on-android-even-though-they-print-the-sam)
- [Comparing java Strings with ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940521/comparing-java-strings-with)
- [How can I compare String value with ArrayList of String type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607888/how-can-i-compare-string-value-with-arraylist-of-string-type-in-java)
- [How can I compare two strings in java and define which of them is smaller than the other alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153496/how-can-i-compare-two-strings-in-java-and-define-which-of-them-is-smaller-than-th)

Comment: ok, I 've changed to equals, the problem now is that print me [1,2] instead of[2] ?

Comment: That's because you *add* `count` to the list each time you increment it. Either just print `count` instead of `list`, or remove the previous `count` from `list` before you add it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
list.get(i).equals("x");
```

!= / == only checks the reference.

I don't knwo why you're using a ArrayList to count. You would probably something like that:

```
int count = 0;
for (String s : table.getValue()) {
    if (s.equals("x")) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println( count );
```

Comment: i need array list, as getValue returns me an Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

For String you should use equals method.

```
int ct = 0;
for (String str : table.getValue()) {
    if ("x".equals(str)) { // "x".equals to avoid NullPoniterException
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(ct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for both the elements as well as the size, I would recommend Guava's [Iterables.filter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method

```
List<String> filtered = Lists.newArrayList(
                     Iterables.filter(myList, 
                                      Predicates.equalTo("x")));
int count = filtered.size();
```

But as everyone else has pointed out, the reason your code is not working is the `==`